# F# making a API request to a graphql endpoint

Tags: f#, graphql

I try to get some data from a grqphql endpoint with F#.
I use Fsharp.Data

```
let apiQuery = """query findData {
                  apiData(Model:{
                                 PageNumber: 1,
                                 PageSize: 100
                                 })
                                 {
                                  ErrorMessage Success ValidationResult TotalCount
                                  Data{
                                      ItemId
                                       }
                                  }
                                 }"""

let queryGraphQl () = 
  Http.RequestString
    ( apiUrl,
      headers = [ ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json;
        Authorization ("bearer " + token)
        ],
      body =
        TextRequest apiQuery
     )
```

But I get `(500) Internal Server Error`

The same in Python works fine:

```
query_headers = {
          "Authorization": 'bearer %s' % token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }

response = requests.post(url, json={'query': apiQuery},  headers=query_headers)
```

Any suggestions what I am missing?

In Postman I have to add
Content-Length and Host like to be calculated when request is sent.

Comment: TextRequest sets the body of the request to the string, but since you're doing a POST, you probably intend the body to be key/value pairs.  I think your Python code is doing that, it's setting the key 'query' to the query string.  You probably want to use FormValues instead of TextRequest. (Not really relevent, but that shouldn't really cause your server to cough up a 500, ideally here it would return 400 (Bad Request)). Try inspecting the exact text that the Python request contains (using Fiddler or something like that), then making sure your F# request is sending pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I was trying it but not finding the query with Fiddler or Wireshark. Could be python or the https URL I am making the requests to. I also was trying it with FormValues and the query parameter of `HttpRequestString`. But no success so far.

Comment: This is a bit hard to debug, because we cannot obviously run your code - would you be able to see if this works against some public GraphQL API endpoint? If you get issues then, it will allow us to try & debug this. I found a useful list here: https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-apis

Comment: @TomasPetricek   Good advice for future questions and tests. I solved it with Piotr Rodaks answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the F# and Python code is not equivalent. The Python code contains additional `query` keyword in the payload.

I don't know the specifics of your particular endpoint, but I wrote similar code using one of the public interfaces.

```
open System.Net
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.HttpRequestHeaders


let key = "********-****-****-****-*************"
let uri k = $"https://api.everbase.co/graphql?apikey={k}"
let gurl = uri key


let apiQuery = """{ "query" : 
                       "{ client { ipAddress { country { name } city { name } } } }"
                  }"""


let connectToGraph apiUrl apiQuery = 
    try
        let res = Http.RequestString( url = apiUrl, httpMethod="POST", body = TextRequest apiQuery, headers = [ ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json; UserAgent "mozilla" ])
        
        res
    with
    | _ as ex -> ex.Message

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let res = connectToGraph gurl apiQuery
    printf "Response: %A" res
    0
```

I suppose you should separate the `query` in your F# code from the rest of the definition with a `':'`. Also the actual payload should be wrapped in quotes/double quotes to form a valid Json value.

Comment: This was the right direction. Also I had to remove the `findData` in my query, that I was using in Postman and Python. Thanks a lot!